# OpenCL: __local semantics

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I am just wondering what is the semantic of the following kernel

```
#define T float
__kernel foo(){
    __local T bar[32];
    __local T a;
}
```

is bar/a shared between a work-group or every work-item will create a separate copy of bar/a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both shared between the work-group, so there will only be one copy of `bar` and `a` per workgroup.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can find reference like that? Do I have to look it up from the specification?

Comment: @dorafmon just use the spec, it's relatively organized and of course searchable.